# Problems with foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that posts data for 2 fields related to specific rows. The form can vary in number of rows for updating dependent on who is using it. However it is not updating any part of the table. If I take the while loop out it will only update the last row. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$p){ ${$k}=$p; }

if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rank FROM accounts WHERE tag='$tag'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        //Set Variables
        $query = "UPDATE accounts SET rank=$rank WHERE id=$m_id";
        mysql_query($query);

}
}
```

Comment: I believe you should put this if{...} part inside foreach? It only executes once.

Comment: Your update isn't in a loop.  There will be only one update.  You must loop on the answer somehow.  You should post the form that you submit.

Comment: If you are new to PHP and MYSQL, please read the red box at the top of [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). These functions should no longer be used. Also, you should be using prepared statements, rather than expanding variables in query strings.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Update'])) {
        $result = mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET rank=".$_POST['rank']." WHERE tag='".$_POST['tag']."'");
        mysql_query($query);

}
```

better read mysql and php properly.

Comment: That won't work as it isn't taking into consideration that different ranks for specific accounts. Even adjusting for this will not update the rows correctly.

Comment: what you are trying to do here $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rank FROM accounts WHERE tag='$tag'");

Comment: Which if it did work would just update all accounts with the same tag to the same rank. In form you could have m_id = 1 && rank = 2, m_id = 2 && rank = 1, with the same $tag. It needs to able to update the rank for specific m_id's from a selection of options